How to lock or blank the local screen when a remote user connects ubuntu 24 gnome remote desktop
While using the inbuilt gnome remote desktop, I'd like the local monitor being locked or blurred, so nobody near of it could see what I'm doing (as it works on windows rdp host). I know about ssh and about possibility to create new session, for example, through xorg connections, but I need to continue remotely what I was doing (in gnome gui) locally some hours (with blurring host screen) and, then, I need to continue locally what I was doing remotely some hours ago. Probably extending virtual monitor usage may help? But looks like I can not get access remotely to virtual and to the main local monitor in parallel (if I could - I would just open remote session on 2 monitors and drug all working windows to virtual monitor). Thanks!

sudo loginctl lock-sessions

@petep, thanks, but it is not. If I list sessions I can see only one. So, it is shared among local screen and remote connection to that. If I lock it, I will just lock my own access to the current session. I want to lock/blur only view of a local host monitor and continue working remotely. I suppose it may be connected to creating of virtual screens which would not being seen locally on host monitor (in the same local session) but would seen on remote computer (as windows host rdp does, but it is not sharing session in parallel, it is kicked out current user when another connected - it is ok)
